# Issues using 'this' in IIFE inside object literals in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have written a simple **school** object. I want to calculate the **age** and store it at the same time. However if I use an IIFE to do this, it seems like ***this*** becomes undefined. It works fine if I make it a normal function.

Please help!

```
const date = new Date();
const currentYear = date.getFullYear();

let school = {
  name: "International Public School",
  yoe: 1970,
  age: (function() {
    return currentYear - this.yoe;
  })()
};
console.log(school);
```

Also can someone tell me how to achieve the same using arrow functions?